# RuntimeError: Tensor for 'out' is on CPU, Tensor for argument #1 'self' is on CPU, but expected them to be on GPU (while checking arguments for addmm)

Tags: python, pytorch

```
label = torch.LongTensor(label).cuda()

img_channels = 3

img_size = 256

x = torch.randn((2, img_channels, img_size, img_size)).cuda()

gen = Generator(img_channels, 9).cuda()

pred = gen(x, label)

print(pred.shape)
```

When I want to use my GPU device, the code have some error : `RuntimeError: Tensor for 'out' is on CPU, Tensor for argument #1 'self' is on CPU, but expected them to be on GPU (while checking arguments for addmm).`

However,when I delete cuda(), my code can work well. The correct answer is `torch.Size([2, 3, 256, 256])`. Where is the CPU tensor?

---

**Update:** Actually I found the problem occured in a Linear strcture.

```py
class Linear_f(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, label_shape, img_shape):
    super().__init__()
    self.linear = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(label_shape, img_shape))      
  def forward(self, x):
    y = self.linear(x)
    return y
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of `Generator`, as well as the *full* error traceback?

Comment: Actually I found the problem occured in a Linear strcture.                                       
```class Linear_f(nn.Module):                             
    def __init__(self, label_shape, img_shape):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(label_shape, img_shape)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        y = self.linear(x)
        return y```

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Comment: @Ivan
 I do not solve it. Finally, I put the linear layer into another function. After that it works, the problem is very strange.

Comment: is you Linear model part of the Gen model? and bte it is better to use "device" param.
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
x = x.to(device) or  x = torch.randn((2, img_channels, img_size, img_size), device=device)

Comment: Maybe your linear module was previously not registered as a submodule of `Generator`, and when you call `cuda()` on `gen`, that linear module is not moved to cuda. But we need to see the code of `Generator` to be sure.